# Use timer to trigger an event in program at specific time

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have my timer code displaying the time correctly on my program, and I want to trigger an event to happen at a 6:31.  How do I get the program to preform a button click or trigger the event that the button handles.  The program works when I run and press the button, but I want it to happen automatically at 6.31 without me pressing it.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: Well 631pm or am? Also wheres your button or code you want to fire.. In the tick event just check the current time if its what you need do something...

Comment: 6.31 am yeah.   This is the code for the button I am trying to get to to activate...Can I just get rid of the button click alltogether?                                              Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest =

Answer (score 0):

In your Tick event:

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now

If (18 = now.Hour) AndAlso (31 = now.Minute) Then   
    ' Change 18 to 6 is you want AM instead of PM
    ' Do something here
End If
```

This is the naive version.  Your question is lacking in details so I did not elaborate on the code.
At a minimum you may need to ensure that once the "event" happens it can't happen again.